# Why is my constructor being called over and over?

Tags: static, namespaces, instance

I've got the following h file:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_DATA_H_
#define GLOBAL_DATA_H_

class GlobalData
{
  public:
    GlobalData();
    ...
  private:
    ...
};

namespace global_data
{
  static GlobalData globalDataInstance;
}

#endif
```

Countless files include the header file above, and access global_data::globalDataInstance.  If I put a breakpoint in GlobalData's constructor body, I see that, when I run the application, the constructor gets called countless times.  Why is this?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't show where `globalDataInstance` is initialized. It would also help to include the code of at least on place where `globalDataInstance` is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that declaring static variables within a namespace does not do what I thought, according to this post:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/134682-initializing-static-variable-inside-namespace

> If you include this header in more
>   than one source file you will get
>   multiple variables. If you change the
>   value of the variable in one file you
>   will not see the change in another
>   file.

It appears the property thing to do would be to declare the namespace variable using extern instead of static.